# How do I get the selected value from ui object?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This control has the following event `select`:

```
select( event, ui )
```

How do I get the selected value from `ui` object

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected value from the aptly-named `value` property exposed by the `item` member of the `ui` object:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.item.value);
}
```